# Django: where to compute data? In view or in form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In Django, where is the best place to compute data that will be displayed? For instance, I need to create a list of elements from a model, but also computing subtotals and other values from those elements.

Where should these computations take place? In the view or in the form?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What type of form are you talking about? Should the computations be stored some where? What do you mean by "create a list of elements"? How are you using a form here?

Comment: I have a calendar with a list of items on each day; I need to have weekly subtotals, and the possibility (in the form) to add or update items. So there's a static part in the form, showing the calendar, and a part with fields to edit items

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the view.

Forms are primarily used to get information from the user into the database.